# Null pointer on Select all on click on header check box android

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, android-checkbox

I am using this block of code for selecting all the checkboxes of my custom listview :

```
     listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getParent(), contactList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
check_all = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_all);
    check_all.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //listview = getListView();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v1) {
                   int size = listview.getAdapter().getCount();
                    boolean checked = listview.isItemChecked(0);
                    for(int i=1; i<size; i++) {
                        listview.setItemChecked(i, checked);
                          CheckBox check = (CheckBox) listview.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkbox); // line no 417
//                          
//                      if(checked)
//                      {
//                            check.setChecked(true);
//                          
//                      }
                        //  check.setChecked(false);

                    }
            }
        });
```

Mylogcat :

```
05-27 16:10:46.224: E/AndroidRuntime(5870): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 16:10:46.224: E/AndroidRuntime(5870):     at com.ht.abc.SettingActivity$5.onClick(SettingActivity.java:417)
05-27 16:10:46.224: E/AndroidRuntime(5870):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
05-27 16:10:46.224: E/AndroidRuntime(5870):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:105)
05-27 16:10:46.224: E/AndroidRuntime(5870):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
05-27 16:10:46.224: E/AndroidRuntime(5870):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-27 16:10:46.224: E/AndroidRuntime(5870):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

I have also tried :

Code :

in xml :

```
 android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
```

in my activity :

```
check_all.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                    for(int i=0;i< listview.getAdapter().getCount();i++){
                        listview.setItemChecked(i,b);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

This is also not working for me.

Comment: What is the line 417 in your code?

Comment: are you sure you cant try with `OnCheckedChangeListener`. And regarding logic ,if you are having view recycling this will fail. try something with viewHolder/DataHolder and notifying adapter data has changed

Answer (score 1):

You have `//listview = getListView();` commented, so likely when you are trying to use the `listview`, is null. Uncomment that line.

```
check_all = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_all);
    check_all.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            listview = getListView(); // <---- THIS LINE
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v1) {
                   int size = listview.getAdapter().getCount();
                    boolean checked = listview.isItemChecked(0);
                    for(int i=1; i<size; i++) {
                        listview.setItemChecked(i, checked);
                          CheckBox check = (CheckBox) listview.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
//                          
//                      if(checked)
//                      {
//                            check.setChecked(true);
//                          
//                      }
                        //  check.setChecked(false);

                    }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Tell me what is the line 417

Comment: It is  CheckBox check = (CheckBox) listview.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkbox); // line no 417
//

Comment: It seems like listview.getChildAt is not  returning any view. You should try nizammoidu answer.

Answer (score 1):

try something like  this

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mData);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_all);
    chkAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            for(int i=0;i< getListView().getAdapter().getCount();i++){
                getListView().setItemChecked(i,b);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

You dont need to manually check or uncheck the checkbox. call `setItemChecked`  followed by `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter

Comment: Yes, that would be more appropriated.